# Java version of "Pointer Pointer"

Tags: java, reference

I have a situation I've run into a couple of times, where multiple classes from different parts of the architecture want to be looking at the same data structure, which may be entirely replaced (for instance, when a newer version comes from the network.) If I keep the data structure and update the information that's easy enough (everything can reference the same one, and will get the up-to-date info when they look), but if the reference is re-assigned entirely, that isn't reflected elsewhere.

I had an idea to make a super-generic wrapper like:

```
public class Wrapper<T>{
    public T _value;
}
```

With the idea that you would never re-assign the wrapper, just the value inside it. All the different components could then point to the wrapper, and the inner value could be re-assigned cleanly when a "new" version came along. (I think I've seen this done with `**` in C.)

But, I'm suspicious that I've never seen this before. Is there a better way to address this problem?

Comment: [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) might be a good choice, so you are guaranteed up-to-date reads on multiple threads.

Comment: Additionally, consider adding `version` field to instance of updatable data structure, so observers can detect if data was updated when they were looking at something else.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

```
String initialReference = "initial value referenced";

AtomicReference<String> atomicStringReference =
    new AtomicReference<String>(initialReference);

String newReference = "new value referenced";
//directly update
atomicReference.set(newReference);

//compare and set
boolean exchanged = atomicStringReference.compareAndSet(initialReference, newReference);
System.out.println("exchanged: " + exchanged);

exchanged = atomicStringReference.compareAndSet(initialReference, newReference);
System.out.println("exchanged: " + exchanged);

//get value
String reference = atomicReference.get();
```

Code example from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/atomicreference.html)

Comment: I went with that, though I feel a little guilty, since the thing I'm representing isn't strictly immutable (sometimes I modify it, sometimes I want to replace it)

Comment: @EdwardPeters so what? The pointer pointer part will work. If your object is mutable and you're working with a multi-threaded environment, you'll need to handle concurrency there too. You may consider using AtomicReference for your class's mutable fields too.

Comment: @Bohemian Yeah, I synchronized on it, but the documentation I read for `AtomicReference` said "Immutable" a lot, so I'm worried I might be breaking a contract somewhere.